# linker delets library and does not recognize it

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I am compiling a C program with g++ and linking it to a library mylib.lib which is located in the same folder as the sourcecode by:

```
user$ g++ myprog.c -o mylib.lib
```

and the compiler behaves in a strange way. first of all it gives the error 'undefined reference to fun1' . this should not happen because fun1 is in mylib.lib. secondly it deletes mylib.lib . I also tried a different way:

```
user$ g++ myprog.c mylib.lib
```

In this case I get the same error: 'undefined reference to fun1'
Finally I tried to add mylib by:

1. renamed mylib.lib to libmylib.lib

2.

```
user$ g++ myprog.c -L/Dima/Tests -l mylib
```

In this case the error is 'cannot find lmylib' although it is located in /Dima/Tests. how do I compile it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You're not building a library, you are trying to create an *executable* program named `mylib.lib`. That's why the linker is invoked.

If you want to create a library, it depends on the toolchain you target, but generally speaking you only create *object* files, and create an archive of those object files.

For the GNU toolchain (GCC and the GNU binutils linker) you use the [`ar`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/ar.html) program to create this archive.

```
$ g++ mylib.c -c             # Create object file named `mylib.o`
$ ar crv libmylib.a mylib.o  # Create the static library
```

Now you have a static library containing the object file `myprog.o` which is compiled from `myprog.c`. To use it do something like

```
$ g++ myprog.c -L. -lmylib -o myprog
```

The above command tells the linker to look in the current directory (`-L.`) and link with the library `mylib` (the linker automatically looks for `libmylib.a`).

Also, when using the GNU linker it's important that you put the libraries *after* any source or object files.

Comment: yeah sure, you're right. the first version doesn't make any sense. I thought for a second that -o means linking to an object file but of course -o stands for output. but what about the second and third version. shouldn't they work?

Comment: @user3884651 On POSIX systems (like Linux and OSX, and also when using e.g. Cygwin or MinGW) the file-ending of static libraries is `.a`, not `.lib`.